# How to add attribute to button and access it at the global level in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to add an attribute to a button like below

```
   <button type="button" eventlistener (click)="toggleButton()">Toggle</button>
```

I want to add some more logic at the global level for click event, is there anyway that whenever I add a button or any element by adding simple attribute I should be able to listen to them. I got this doubt after watching the code in angular 2 material as below:

```
<button md-button>Click me!</button>
```

Using md-button attribute they have added few styles to the button. In the same way I want to add my custom functionality for my custom attribute. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive for this. 
Check directive to change background color on hover of mouse.

Directive class

```
import { Directive,ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit, HostListener, HostBinding,
Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBetterHighlight]'
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective implements OnInit {

@Input() defaultColor: string = 'transparent';
@Input() highlightColor: string = 'yellow';

@HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroudColor: string;

constructor(private elmentRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

 ngOnInit() {
this.backgroudColor = this.defaultColor;
}
@HostListener('mouseenter') onmouseover(eventData: Event) {
//this.renderer.setStyle(this.elmentRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
this.backgroudColor = this.highlightColor;
}

@HostListener('mouseleave') onmouseleave(eventData: Event) {
//this.renderer.setStyle(this.elmentRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'transparent');
this.backgroudColor = this.defaultColor;
 }
}
```

Template

```
<p appBetterHighlight [defaultColor] = "'green'" [highlightColor] = "'yellow'" >Highlight better paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[eventlistener]'
})
export class EventListener {
    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
        alert('You clicked me');
    }
}
```

Then just add `eventlistener` to anything, and click on it, you will see the alert.

Also, add this directive's class to the `declarations` array in your **root** module

**Note** everything is imported from `@angular/core`